# Ограничение по контрольным точкам

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, media-queries, разметка

Друзья, всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, при создании медиазапросов, как правильней спроектировать контрольные точки? Часто в сети можно встретить руководства по типу "создаем контрольные точки для десктопов, планшетов, смартфонов" - говорю условно. Например, в том же бутстрапе их всего 5. Просто у меня при вёрстке получается около 20. Это нормально? Не получается впихнуть всё в такое маленькое количество.
Большое спасибо за ответы)

Comment: Используйте технологии для адаптивной верстки по максимуму, к примеру, модули CSS Grid и CSS Flexbox часто помогают избавиться от лишних медиа-запросов. Можно также чаще использовать относительные величины измерения вместо фиксированных. Очень частая практика, когда на экранах менее 768px скрывают некоторые меню, сайдбары, элементы с дополнительной информацией. Может быть, что внешний вид ваших макетов на экранах планшетов и телефонов можно спроектировать по-другому, чтобы было меньше запросов.

Comment: В бутстрапе их всего 5 - потому, что это фреймворк, и его задача сделать все максимально просто в ущерб тому, что все что на нем собрано похоже друг на друга как две капли воды. Иногда точек приходится делать больше, если сайт имеет "уникальную" верстку. Вообще это задача дизайнера, расположить блоки так, чтобы контрольных точек было как можно меньше. Дизайнер должен показать, как на разных разрешениях должны выглядеть блоки и как они должны перестраиваться. Если вы хороший верстальшик, но у вас их каждый раз больше 20 - то дизайнер по всей видимости не делает сайт по сетке.

Comment: Это нормально. Бывает, что у многих блоков свои точки перестроения, которые не зависят от других. Некоторые их пишут для блоков отдельно. Например у шапки с логотипом, меню и поиском в один ряд может быть больше точек, чем у галереи-сетки картинок, просто из-за сложности и неоднозначности в разных промежутках. А так согласен с первым комментарием.

Comment: Нормально-то нормально, и все же лучше сокращать количество таких "точек" - банально для того чтобы стили не превращались в мясо. Инструмент сокращения - респонсивная верстка (делай резиновым все-все-все изначально, лишь ограничивая макс.размер разумными величинами: в перспективе такой подход оказывается _значительно_ выгоднее, чем костыляние каждого шага изменения размеров через медиазапросы).

Comment: Но а если мясо в стилях устраивает (это может быть нормально, например, при работе на потоке создания write-only сайтов), то особо сильно переживать из-за медиазапросов сейчас не стоит: потому что в наше время все (или почти все) фронтэндеры ждут стандартизации контейнерных запросов... они в корне изменят подходы к адаптивности, т.к. решение таких задач станет проще сразу на несколько порядков. Конечно же, контейнерные запросы тоже предполагают респонсивность (ее лучше изучить в любом случае).

Comment: Спасибо за Ваши ответы, очень интересно читать)

Answer (score 0):

Просто не надо делать контрольные точки на каждый вариант разрешения экрана, вот и все. Для промежуточных значений сайт должен быть резиновым.

1. Сперва оцениваете на каких системах будет отображаться ваш сайт. Например, вы решили, что он должен работать на разрешениях от 480 пикселей (не очень старый айфон, программные пиксели) и выше вплоть до Full HD (1920 пикселей) по горизонтали. Все, что выше Full HD, к примеру, будет просто обрамлено полями по бокам, как, например, наш любимый StackOverflow (который заточен под 1280 пикселей, если кто не в курсе).
2. первая (а точнее, нулевая) контрольная точка у вас будет... подразумеваемая. Это те самые минимальные 480 пикселей. Это значит, что на устройства с меньшим экраном (айфон-4, например) вам наплевать, и все, что вам надо - чтобы был горизонтальный скроллинг. `min-width` для `body`, и вуаля.
3. теперь уж действительно первая точка - это та ширина экрана, при которой дизайн под мелочевку приводит к некрасивому виду. Обычно это 640 пикселей (= 1280 физических пикселей на большинстве андроидов, например).
4. вторая точка - свыше 640 но до ширины среднего планшета включительно. Например, 800 пикселей (ширина 8" планшетов на андроиде). В этот диапазон попадает, например, айпад в вертикальной ориентации.
5. третья точка - планшеты/смартфоны в альбомном виде и мелкие мониторы. Это может быть 1024 или 1280 пикселей. Т.е., медиа-запрос на диапазон 800 < X <= 1024, например.
6. четвертая точка - 99% дисплеев для нормальной работы, а также телевизоров - 1920 пикселей. Т.е., например, 1280 < X <= 1920.
7. все, что выше, отдельной точки обычно не требует (обернули весь контент во враппер с максимальной шириной 1920 минус скроллбар, и радуетесь), но если надо, можно и медиа-запрос на X > 1920 накатать - например, для показа контента в две колонки на 4к экранах.

Ну а в пределах каждого из этих диапазонов дизайн должен быть нормально резиновым, либо оборачивать во враппер размером с минимальную ширину минус скроллбар.

---

Как-то так.

ИМХО.